# How can I implement multiselection in Qt in TreeView when user holds key CTRL on keyboard ?

Tags: c++, qt, treeview

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    MyFileSystemModel model;
};
```

My file cpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    model.setRootPath(QDir::rootPath());

     ui->treeView->setModel(&model);
     ui->treeView->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
     ui->treeView->setDragEnabled(true);
}
```

I used the MultiSelection property, but it works only when I click on items in treeview with mouse, I don't want to select a few items without pressing CTRL on keyboard. How can I check if user pressed CTRL and then select items ?

Comment: I think there is an ExtendedSelection mode for this. Huh

Answer (score 4):

QTreeview has a virtual function to set selection mode.

You can set the mode to multiselection like this:

```
QTreeView treeView;
treeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::MultiSelection);
```

Also for Multiselection with ctrl key use this:

```
QTreeView treeView;
treeView.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::ExtendedSelection);
```

more info about QTreeview [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html).